# How to use loadlibrary and getprocaddress from gfortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to learn how to call a function in a fortran dll from a fortran executable on windows. I'm working with gfortran 4.7 and photran in eclipse.

My test dll has a single function in hello.f90:

*hello.f90*

```
subroutine hello
    implicit none
    print *, "Hello World!"
end subroutine hello
```

with the following makefile:

```
all:
    gfortran -Wall -c hello.f90
    gfortran -shared -o hello.dll hello.o
```

Dependency Walker confirms that the function "hello_" is exported.

Now I'm trying to build a program that calls it dynamically. I've built the following based on examples I've found online, but it doesn't compile:

*main.f90*

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: p
    pointer (q, hello)
    p = loadlibrary("hello.dll")
    q = getprocaddress(p, "hello_")
    call hello
end program main
```

*makefile*

```
all:
    gfortran -Wall -pedantic -fcray-pointer main.f90
```

The error message is that function LoadLibrary (and getprocaddress) has no IMPLICIT type. I suspect that means those functions aren't defined and I need to include their headers somehow. Is that right? I've found a declaration for loadlibrary in c:\mingw\include\winbase.h

cheers,

Marc

Comment: I do not use Windows anymore, so I am not 100% sure, but shouldn't there be a `char(0)` after "hello.dll" and "hello_" to make it end the line??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress are Windows API routines.  Like any non-intrinsic function, you need to declare the type of those functions and, given the nature of those API's, you also need to go further and provide the full interface.

If you are compiling for 32 bit Windows then those API's use the stdcall calling convention.  You need to use gfortran source directive extensions to designate that.

(On 64 bit Windows stdcall is defined to be the same as the C calling convention - the source directive has no effect.)

For calling convention control, if I change your DLL code to:

```
SUBROUTINE hello() BIND(C, NAME='hello')
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRINT *, 'Hello'
END SUBROUTINE hello
```

then the following main program will load the resulting DLL and execute that procedure.

```
PROGRAM Main
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
      C_F_PROCPOINTER, C_FUNPTR, C_INTPTR_T,  &
      C_NULL_CHAR, C_CHAR, C_ASSOCIATED

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTERFACE 
     FUNCTION LoadLibrary(lpFileName) BIND(C,NAME='LoadLibraryA')
        USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_INTPTR_T, C_CHAR
        IMPLICIT NONE 
        CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR) :: lpFileName(*) 
        !GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: LoadLibrary 
        INTEGER(C_INTPTR_T) :: LoadLibrary 
     END FUNCTION LoadLibrary 

     FUNCTION GetProcAddress(hModule, lpProcName)  &
         BIND(C, NAME='GetProcAddress')
       USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY:  &
           C_FUNPTR, C_INTPTR_T, C_CHAR
       IMPLICIT NONE
       !GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: GetProcAddress
       TYPE(C_FUNPTR) :: GetProcAddress
       INTEGER(C_INTPTR_T), VALUE :: hModule
       CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR) :: lpProcName(*)
     END FUNCTION GetProcAddress      
  END INTERFACE

  ABSTRACT INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE hello_intf() BIND(C)
      IMPLICIT NONE
    END SUBROUTINE hello_intf
  END INTERFACE

  INTEGER(C_INTPTR_T) :: module_handle
  TYPE(C_FUNPTR) :: proc_address
  PROCEDURE(hello_intf), BIND(C), POINTER :: my_proc

  !****      

  module_handle = LoadLibrary(C_CHAR_'hello.dll' // C_NULL_CHAR)
  IF (module_handle == 0) STOP 'Unable to load DLL'

  proc_address = GetProcAddress( module_handle,  &
      C_CHAR_'hello' // C_NULL_CHAR )
  IF (.NOT. C_ASSOCIATED(proc_address))  &
      STOP 'Unable to obtain procedure address'

  CALL C_F_PROCPOINTER(proc_address, my_proc)

  CALL my_proc

END PROGRAM Main
```

Comment: One also has to link against the static import library (`.lib`) of the DLL.

Comment: @HristoIliev Which DLL are you referring to?

Comment: The one that contains `GetProcAddressA` and `LoadLibraryA`, namely `kernel32.dll`. The code has to be linked against `kernel32.lib` from the Win32 SDK.

Comment: @IanH, thanks a bunch. It works perfectly. I do have a question though, if you don't mind. I'm not clear how BIND(C,NAME='LoadLibraryA') works. Where is LoadLibraryA defined, since I'm not linking any header files or libraries explicitly there must be some implicit linking going on somewhere?

Comment: @IanH, on closer inspection I think you are declaring the function prototypes in the interface section which allows it to compile, and some magical minGW goodness is resolving the windows system calls at runtime. Is that right? cheers.

Comment: @marcp, `LoadLibrary` has two versions: an ANSI strings version `LoadLibraryA` and an Unicode (wide) version `LoadLibraryW`. Both are exported by `kernel32.dll`. Basically all Windows programs are linked against `kernel32.lib` from the Win32 SDK, which is the static export library of `kernel32.dll`. Usually simple C programs (ones without explicit Win32 API calls) as well as Fortran programs link only against their run-time libraries, but it looks like the MinGW versino of the `gfortran` compiler also links implicitly with `kernel32.lib`.

Comment: @marcp, in this case the interface blocks only describe the function arguments and the `BIND(C,NAME="...")` gives the right function name (one without the special name mangling of the Fortran compiler) so the Fortran compiler can generate the proper call sequence and refer the proper external symbol. This is the Fortran equivalent of the C function prototypes, found in the header files. There is nothing magical about it :)

Comment: @HristoIliev I thought for a moment there you were referring to the static import library of hello.dll.  Yes - the -lkernel32 (and some other system libs) addition to the link line is hard-coded in the gcc driver on Windows (C programs get it too, unless you are doing something special).