# Use 'dfwin' Fortran library with gfortran

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I try to load dynamically DLL library in fortran, so I need to use `loadlibrary` and `getprocaddress` function from `dfwin` library.

But when I compile this:

```
program helloworld
    use dfwin
end
```

I just got:

```
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'dfwin.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

Can I install or link in any way `dfwin` module to **gfortran** GCC compiler ?

Comment: What commands are you using to compile your code?

Comment: Just makefile with `gfortran hello.f90 -o hello.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The mod file generated by a compiler is specific to that compiler (in some cases, specific to a compiler version).

(Even if you had the source for the dfwin module, it uses extensions that are specific to the DEC/Compaq/Intel compiler lineage.)

Comment: Ok, so which steps I have to follow to succefuly develow with Fortran and `loadlibrary` function, to use 32-bit Windows DLL also compiled in fortran? Which compiler to use?

Comment: If you want to use the DFWIN module then you'll need the Intel compiler or one of its ancestors.  If you just want to use gfortran then perhaps answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165801/how-to-use-loadlibrary-and-getprocaddress-from-gfortran) rather recent question might help.